# IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.eecommon.api.config.GlassfishConfiguration.<init>

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I'm doing a JSF project in netbeans 8.02 using Glassfish v2. Somehow, when I right click on the project and click on properties, it gives no response but a message: netbeans: Unexpected Exception.

```
> IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
> org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.eecommon.api.config.GlassfishConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/netbeans/modules/j2ee/deployment/devmodules/api/J2eeModule;)V
> from class
> org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.sun.ide.j2ee.ModuleConfigurationImpl
```

Comment: [`java.lang.IllegalAccessError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html) states, "*Thrown if an application attempts to access or modify a field, or to call a method that it does not have access to. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.*" So, something might have been changed, perhaps, during upgrading the IDE. This is, after all, not related to JSF at all.